# Hide table row after bootstrap model is hidden

Tags: jquery, ajax, hide, bootstrap-modal

the scenario:

when user click on a delete button to delete a product from database, it always ask a confirmation on a bootstrap model with a confirmation message and a delete button.

so if user clicks on a delete button from a model.. the product gets deleted from database.. and a message in a model shows the successful deletion message using ajax...

now i would like to hide the row from where users has clicked on a delete button.. every row of a table contains the product details and a delete button, the delete button passes the product id from which the product is identified and deleted successfully using ajax call..

so to hide the tr i have written this:

The Table:

```
<tr id="<?= $row->id ?>"> //i have passed the product id to a tr.. so that i can hide it..
<td><?= $row->product_name ?></td>
<td>
   <a href="#delete-model" id="delete" role="button" 
      data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?= $row->id ?>">
      delete
   </a>
</td>
</tr>
```

the id="delete" passes the id value to delete ajax call and gets successfully deleted..

The ajax success method:

```
  success: function(data) {
     $("#message").html(data.data);
     $('#trId').attr('value', data.trId); //example #productid
      //data.trId is the product id, to identify the tr 
       as i have passed the product id above to a tr as <tr id="<?= $row->id ?>">
   }
```

now when user closes the model, i would like to hide the tr from where user has clicked on a delete button.

this event get fired when user closes the model:

```
$('#delete-model').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $("#message").text(''); 
        $($("trId").val()).hide();
        $('#trId').attr('value', '');
    });
```

but it is not working as expected.. any help or suggestion would be a great help thanks in advance..

Comment: It should be `$($("#trId").val()).hide();` (with "#"), shouldn't it?

Comment: ohhhh... such a great fool i am.. thanks @Regent Sir.. now its working perfectly..

Comment: @AmitKumar the '#' is already attached with the data.trId from the ajax response

Comment: Should I post this as an answer, or you will delete the question?

Comment: you can.. i have no issues.. i will mark it as answer.. cause it just save me a lot of time.. and google search...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
$($("trId").val()).hide();
```

It should be:

```
$($("#trId").val()).hide();
```